# Android vulnerable to JavaScript interface injection issue

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-audience-network

Today i have received email like following,

Security alert

Your app includes a WebView that is vulnerable to JavaScript interface injection. Please see this [Google Help Center article](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9095419) for details.

Vulnerable locations:

com.facebook.ads.internal.view.b.a->

com.facebook.ads.internal.view.m->c

Please fix the issue before: 03/27/2019

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Update:

I am using this sdk of facabook.

```
'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.1'
```

Comment: you need to add the relevant code of your app

Comment: What do you mean by need to add relevant code to my app? can you please collaborate?

Comment: you get that error because you are probably doing something unsafe in the code of your app.

Comment: I have just used facebook library for facebook audience network. Also there is no change in the library.

Comment: but how did you use it? and what version of it? did you checkout the bugs list of facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of the SDK is 5.1.0, you should upgrade: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/download/

Date of the update: October 31, 2018

It should hopefully fix your issue. If that does not solve it, you could create a bug report so they include a fix in the next versions: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/

Comment: Thanks, i will check this

Comment: Hi Hardik, does this fix your Google warning ? Thks

Comment: Hey @Hardik, did updating the SDK fix your issue? Thanks.